# Package brown-perception on armhf

Tags: gscam, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, armhf, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use a webcam on armhf. For testing on x86, with Electric/Ubuntu 10.04 it works and I can use gscam. With Groovy/Ubuntu1204 on x86, it will work as well with gscam. However, I find that gscam depends on the brown-perception package which isn't available for armhf on groovy and hydro. This most likely explains why my earlier attempts of running the gscam driver didn't work out. Does brown-perception (Groovy) build for armhf or should I use e.g. uvc_cam or libuvc_camera ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164201/package-brown-perception-on-armhf/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had good results using the uvc_camera package in Hydro on armhf, and it's already available as a deb for ARM.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-13**:
After installing uvc_camera and deps, I run "rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node" and get a couple of messages ending with "opening /dev/video0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  couldn't open /dev/video0
Aborted (core dumped)" The cam is connected.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-14**:
After chmod a+rw on /dev/video0 it opens, but after reading it, it looks for /dev/video1 which isnt there and so far I can't find how to disable the StereoNode.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
According to the wiki page ( http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera ), the single and stereo nodes should be two separate nodes. I would make sure you're running the correct node.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-14**:
OK, had read the info wrong. I have a working cam now, but find it a bit odd that with the uvc_camera_node, rostopic lists both a left and a right camera. Could this influence the fps ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
I have no idea if this affects the frame rate or not. I would look at the topics in question to see if they're still around because they're published by the camera driver, or if they're still around because something else is subscribing to them.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-14**:
Ok, after restarting roscore, the topics are fine. The fps looks good too for now.